# Simple swaybar example

Tags: sway

I'd like to have a simple, calm status bar for [Sway](https://swaywm.org/) which I use with Arch Linux.

The configurations I found so far use a separate program like [waybar](https://github.com/Alexays/Waybar) or [i3status](https://github.com/i3/i3status). While they look great, I'd like to keep it simple and use `status_command` mentioned in `man sway-bar` directly.

Preferably, this status bar would work equally well with [i3](https://i3wm.org/) which should be possible since Sway aims to have its configuration be compatible with i3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my current status bar:

[image: status bar screenshot sound on]

When audio is muted:

[image: status bar screenshot sound off]

Content of `status.sh` which `~/.config/sway/config` calls:

```bsh
# The Sway configuration file in ~/.config/sway/config calls this script.
# You should see changes to the status bar after saving this script.
# If not, do "killall swaybar" and $mod+Shift+c to reload the configuration.

# The abbreviated weekday (e.g., "Sat"), followed by the ISO-formatted date
# like 2018-10-06 and the time (e.g., 14:01). Check `man date` on how to format
# time and date.
date_formatted=$(date "+%a %F %H:%M")

# "upower --enumerate | grep 'BAT'" gets the battery name (e.g.,
# "/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0") from all power devices.
# "upower --show-info" prints battery information from which we get
# the state (such as "charging" or "fully-charged") and the battery's
# charge percentage. With awk, we cut away the column containing
# identifiers. i3 and sway convert the newline between battery state and
# the charge percentage automatically to a space, producing a result like
# "charging 59%" or "fully-charged 100%".
battery_info=$(upower --show-info $(upower --enumerate |\
grep 'BAT') |\
egrep "state|percentage" |\
awk '{print $2}')

# "amixer -M" gets the mapped volume for evaluating the percentage which
# is more natural to the human ear according to "man amixer".
# Column number 4 contains the current volume percentage in brackets, e.g.,
# "[36%]". Column number 6 is "[off]" or "[on]" depending on whether sound
# is muted or not.
# "tr -d []" removes brackets around the volume.
# Adapted from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=89648
audio_volume=$(amixer -M get Master |\
awk '/Mono.+/ {print $6=="[off]" ?\
$4" ": \
$4" "}' |\
tr -d [])

# Additional emojis and characters for the status bar:
# Electricity: ⚡ ↯ ⭍ 
# Audio:      
# Separators: \| ❘ ❙ ❚
# Misc:     ⭐  ↑ ↓ ✉ ✅ ❎
echo $audio_volume $battery_info  $date_formatted
```

Here's the status bar part of `~/.config/sway/config`:

```bsh
bar {
    position top

    # Keep in mind that the current directory of this config file is $HOME
    status_command while ~/.config/sway/status.sh; do sleep 1; done

    # https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_colors
    colors {
        # Text color of status bar
        statusline #f8b500

        # Background color of status bar
        background #5e227f
    }
}
```

`status.sh` works also with [i3](https://i3wm.org/) when called from `/.config/i3/config` using the same `bar` block shown above.

[Here's a link](https://gitlab.com/bullbytes/dotfiles/-/tree/master/sway) to my current Sway configuration containing `status.sh`.

Answer (score 16):

I have this script at `~/.config/sway/status.sh`:

```bsh
# The Sway configuration file in ~/.config/sway/config calls this script.
# You should see changes to the status bar after saving this script.
# If not, do "killall swaybar" and $mod+Shift+c to reload the configuration.

# Produces "21 days", for example
uptime_formatted=$(uptime | cut -d ',' -f1  | cut -d ' ' -f4,5)

# The abbreviated weekday (e.g., "Sat"), followed by the ISO-formatted date
# like 2018-10-06 and the time (e.g., 14:01)
date_formatted=$(date "+%a %F %H:%M")

# Get the Linux version but remove the "-1-ARCH" part
linux_version=$(uname -r | cut -d '-' -f1)

# Returns the battery status: "Full", "Discharging", or "Charging".
battery_status=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status)

# Emojis and characters for the status bar
#     ⚡  \|
echo $uptime_formatted ↑ $linux_version  $battery_status  $date_formatted
```

The part in `~/.config/sway/config` that defines the status bar is this:

```bsh
bar {
    position top
    # Keep in mind that the current directory of this config file is $HOME
    status_command while ~/.config/sway/status.sh; do sleep 1; done

    colors {
        # Text color of status bar
        statusline #ffffff
        # Background of status bar
        background #323232
    }
    font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono 10
}
```

That's how the bar looks using this configuration:

[image: swaybar]

The above settings works also in [i3](https://i3wm.org/) with an identical result.

You need to have an appropriate font installed to render the emoji characters, for example:

```
pacman -S noto-fonts-emoji
```

or

```
apt install fonts-noto-color-emoji
```

Comment: ```sudo chmod 744 ~/.config/sway/status.sh```

Comment: I used this to get the battery %

`battery_status=$(upower -i $(upower -e | grep 'BAT') | grep -E "percentage" | awk '{print $2}')`

Answer (score 5):

I love bash but I am using a Python script for this. Looks like Python's standard library has lot of utilities for these kind of things.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from psutil import disk_usage, sensors_battery
from psutil._common import bytes2human
from socket import gethostname, gethostbyname
from subprocess import check_output
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

def write(data):
    stdout.write('%s\n' % data)
    stdout.flush()

def refresh():
    disk = bytes2human(disk_usage('/').free)
    ip = gethostbyname(gethostname())
    try:
        ssid = check_output("iwgetid -r", shell=True).strip().decode("utf-8")
        ssid = "(%s)" % ssid
    except Exception:
        ssid = "None"
    battery = int(sensors_battery().percent)
    status = "Charging" if sensors_battery().power_plugged else "Discharging"
    date = datetime.now().strftime('%h %d %A %H:%M')
    format = "Space: %s | Internet: %s %s | Battery: %s%% %s | Date: %s"
    write(format % (disk, ip, ssid, battery, status, date))

while True:
    refresh()
    sleep(1)
```

Here's a screenshot of the bar:

[image: status bar screenshot]

Comment: @Matthias, It is a very simple one since I like minimalism. I think the main advantage is that Python has lot of libraries for this + better data structures (no `cut`, `awk` etc) - so cleaner syntax :-)

Comment: Recently I realized that `psutils` is not part of the standard library, it is very a common one though for cross-platform stuff :-)

Answer (score 1):

[image: swaystatus]

I wrote a lightweight yet feature-rich status bar [swaystatus](https://github.com/NobodyXu/swaystatus) for i3 and sway.

It is written completely in C/C++ to make it as lightweight as possible and specifically, to avoid creating new processes every second as in the Bash script.

It uses libraries like `libupower-glib`, `libasound` and `libnm` to retrieve battery, volume and network information as opposed to using `upower`, `amixer` or `nmcli`.

For backlight, load, and meminfo, it reads directly from `/sys/class/backlight`, `/proc/loadavg` and `/proc/meminfo`.

On my x86-64 computer, it compiles to a single binary that is only 49K large using `clang-11`.